# jQuery: How to grab RadioButton selection?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I need to grab the value of the radiobutton option selected with jQuery. I am using the following code but "str" is undefined in Firebug:

```
 //handling Feed vs. Ingredient RadioButton
            $('[id$=rdoCheck]').change(function() {
                str = $("input[name='rdoCheck']:checked").val();
                //ingredients
                if (str == "ing")
                { $('[id$="lblDescription"]').text("Ingredient") }
                //finished feed
                else if (str == "ffc")
                { $('[id$="lblDescription"]').text("Finished") }

            });
```

Comment: Can you show the corresponding HTML code?

Comment: You don't need quotes in the name attribute selector. `$("input[name=rdoCheck]:checked")` is sufficient.

Comment: Declare your variables with `var`!!!  Geez this happens like *every single day* here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using ASP.Net.  When you look at the rendered html, you'll see it's messing with (prefixing) the `name` attribute just like it does with IDs.

You'll need to also use an [ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) on it, like this:

```
var str = $("input[name$=rdoCheck]:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

I add classes to my .net generated elements so that I can use simpler jQuery selectors eg

```
<asp:textbox id="txtName" CssClass="name"/>

$('input.name').text();
```

Note: You can specify an absolute identifer in asp.net 4.0

Comment: This works for your example, but not so well for radio button groups, for example if you have a user control with a group and multiple copies of it, how would you get a specific group?...gets kinda messy, better off keying off the name...also fixed in 4.0

Comment: @Nck - I would specify a different CssClass for each usercontrol instance (unless you are using a repeater or something, then we are potentially in a world of hurt with jQuery!)